# How to trigger a click wherever an HTML element appears with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I tried

```
await page.click("div:contains('text')")
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it not possible to do so? Would I somehow have to grab the wrapper/"parent" of the HTML first, then call a click on it?

Answer (score 0):

first check your element in not empty then fire click trigger.

```
  if (!$('#element').is(':empty'))
    {
         document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
    }
```